# Cannot install sent2trash with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I tried to install `send2trash` with pip and got the following error message:

```
$ pip install send2trash
Collecting send2trash
  Downloading Send2Trash-1.3.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: send2trash
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for send2trash
  Stored in directory: /Users/kylefoley/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/15/76/b3/a81bb5d0bfc6157d1e5df52d34cbea6ffe8a0fc6fea83bddb0
Successfully built send2trash
Installing collected packages: send2trash
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 310, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 71, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/send2trash'
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When I try to import the module i get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'send2trash'
```

Maybe the problem is that I'm using Python 3 and the pip installed it into Python 2.7. I don't know how to install send2trash so that python 3 uses it.

## Update:

Hi Marekful,  Thanks for trying to help me out.  I tried your suggestions but they did not work

```
$ sudo pip install send2trash
Password:
The directory '/Users/kylefoley/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/kylefoley/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting send2trash
Installing collected packages: send2trash
Successfully installed send2trash-1.3.0
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kylefoley$ sudo -H pip install send2trash
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): send2trash in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was indeed due to the fact that send2trash was downloaded in the python2.7 folder.

```
(Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (18.0)).
```

I just went into this folder and copied the two folders named `send2trash` and `Send2Trash-1.5.0.dist-info` into the similar path corresponding to the python3.7 version:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Now it works for me. Hope this helps.

**Later edit:**
To install a module in a certain version of Python on Linux and Mac OS X use the -m switch in the command line:

```
python2   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 2
python2.7 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 2.7
python3   -m pip install SomePackage  # default Python 3
python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Build succeeds but install fails due to permission problems.

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/send2trash'

Run the command with `sudo`:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kylefoley$ sudo pip install send2trash
```

Comment: see update.  (I don't know why stackoverflow does not allow us to make longer comments)

Comment: This time it installed successfully: `Successfully installed send2trash-1.3.0`

Comment: yes but it still does not work. I still get the same error in Python.

Comment: Check you installation. Messages about upgrading pip is recommendation: `You should consider upgrading`...

Comment: So why don't you follow the instructions to upgrade pip: `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` and then try installing / upgrading send2trash?

Comment: because if I upgrade then other things that do work will stop working.

Comment: Besides the problem is not with pip install but with python because the pip install is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip3` instead of just `pip` to run pip on python 3.*
First update your package index:

```
sudo apt update
```

If you have not installed pip on python 3 yet, do this:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

If you have already installed pip on python 3, update it:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then install `send2trash`:

```
pip3 install send2trash
```